# Is there a better way than Thread.Sleep() to wait for example for PrintOut()?

Tags: c#, sleep, infopath, office-interop

I have made a small function which should print some InfoPath files. It is necessary to stop at some points the thread shortly that everything works fine. If I remove the `Thread.Sleep();` for example the function close the application to fast. 
Now I would like to know, if there is a nicer way to solve that problem instead to stop the thread?

Here a piece of the function:

```
Application InfoPath = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application();
XDocument InfoPathXml = InfoPath.XDocuments.Open(XmlFile);
Thread.Sleep(Sleep);
InfoPathXml.PrintOut();
Thread.Sleep(Sleep);
InfoPath.Quit();
Thread.Sleep(Sleep);
```

The first sleep waits, until InfoPath  has opened the document. The second one, waits for creating the print job. The last one, waits until the file is saved.

**Edit**
Here is some new code... But sadly it doesn't work quite well... Only sometimes the event will be fired. Is there any other solution?

```
try
{
    Application InfoPath = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application();
    XDocument InfoPathXml = InfoPath.XDocuments.Open(XmlFile);
    InfoPathXml.OnContextChange += new _XDocumentEventSink2_OnContextChangeEventHandler(XmlFileLoaded);
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    } while (IsFileLocked(TempPath) == true);
    InfoPath.Quit();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    log.Write(exp.Message);
}

static private void XmlFileLoaded(DocEvent pEvent)
{
    pEvent.XDocument.PrintOut();
}
```

**Edit2**

Could anyone imagination why the event is not activated every time. If I start the program, the event is fired every 4th or 5th time.

There are two different cases which happen:

1. The program opens the xml file with InfoPath, and nothing happens,
   it just waits. (Cause of the " IsFileLocked" function.)  The event
   is not triggered.
2. The event is triggered after the first file is open.  After that, the event occurs at every file, everything works fine.

Could it be a problem with cashing the files, or something like that?

**Edit3**

Well, with the following event handling, I could solve the problem:

```
_Application3 InfoPathApplication = null;
ApplicationEvents InfoPathApplicationEvents = null;

InfoPathApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath._Application3)InfoPath;
InfoPathApplicationEvents = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.ApplicationEvents)InfoPathApplication.Events;
InfoPathApplicationEvents.XDocumentOpen += new _ApplicationEvents_XDocumentOpenEventHandler(XmlFileLoaded);


static private void XmlFileLoaded(_XDocument pEvent)
{
    pEvent.PrintOut();
    //pEvent.XDocument.PrintOut();
}
```

Comment: Generally, there should be a feedback provided by InfoPath that you'd wait on.  Thread.Sleep(0) can be used for micro-optimization to give up a timeslice.  Otherwise, using Thread.Sleep() to wait for a result is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: how can you be sure that your printout has finished correctly at your wake up? how can you be sure that the thread does not get awakened by an interrupt?

Comment: @stt-lcu I'm not. I just hope :). This is why I ask for a nicer way.

Comment: @Taz these are just 2 questions you should always ask yourself when working with threads. If you can't properly answer you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @GregC I tried it with the `OnSwitchView`, but sadly the event is not raised every time when the file is opened, that’s weird. Sometime it will, the other time it will not... Also I cannot use `OnLoad`, is there a other solution?

Comment: I think this bit might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.infopath.applicationevents.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Subscribe to [event _ApplicationEvents_QuitEventHandler Quit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.infopath.applicationevents.aspx)
2. Before exiting the app, wait for a semaphore.
3. In the event handler (that is, when the InfoPath app exits), open up the semaphore.

Comment: Did you have a small example? I have some problems with the msdn article and the way how to use the ApplicationEvent. Greetz.

Comment: I found following: [COM Add-in to Add Custom Features to InfoPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa946869.aspx) 
But how they got the InfoPathApplication and InfoPathApplicationEvents object? I thought it should look like: `Application t = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application)InfoPath;
                ApplicationEvents d = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.ApplicationEvents)t.Events;`

Comment: Okay, I got it! See my next **Edit**. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use asyncronous programming. Define a callback function to be invoked after each event. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx).